# User defined type guards without passing a parameter

Tags: typescript, types, typeguards

Let's say I have these classes:

```
export abstract class AbstractSubjectChild<T extends Subject>
{
    protected parent: T | undefined;

    public hasParent()
    {
        return this.parent != null;
    }

    public setParent(parent: T): void
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public getParent(): T | undefined
    {
        return this.parent;
    }
}

class Child extends AbstractSubjectChild<Post>
{   
}
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
const child = new Child();

if (child.hasParent()) {
    const post: Post = child.getParent();
}
```

Is there a way to tell TS compiler to infer the type based on `hasParent()` result without having to explicitly use `as Post` everywhere?

Comment: The simple way is to reorder your code somewhat: ```const post = child.getParent();
if (post) {
    /* The type of `post` here is `Post` */
}```

Comment: i would recommend not coding this like it's java with all the getters and setters.

Comment: @bryan60 - Good point, ```if (child.parent) { /* ...here, `child.parent` will be `Post`, not `Post | undefined` */ }``` if `parent` were public (even if it were an accessor property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export abstract class AbstractSubjectChild<T extends Subject>
{
    protected _parent?: T;

    public set parent(parent: T): void
    {
        this._parent = parent;
    }

    public get parent(): T | undefined
    {
        return this._parent;
    }
}
```

write your class that way and you can do:

```
if (child.parent) {
  const post = child.parent;
  // everywhere in this block scope is now aware of the type of post
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about TS getters and setters (which is ironical considering I use them often in C#). You just have a small mistake - there is no need for `void` at the end of the setter and `parent` parameter type should be `T | undefined`.